# WebView2 does not pass on httponly cookie

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, reportviewer, webview2

I have a problem with WebView that does not do what I expect. I don't want to bore you with the details of why it is done like this, but what I can tell you that at this stage we don't have much of a choice doing it this way.

I retrieve the cookies from the IIS server on a specific url. One of the cookies have some information that I need to pass in a WebView2 call to display a ReportView report. The information in the cookie is basically decoded by the ReportView endpoint, and then allows you to continue. Because WebBrowser in C# is really not the way to go for many reasons, we want to change the Browser component that is used. Another Developer tried to implement WebView2, which is the chromium based browser, but he had endless problems with the implementation, so I took over. First I tried `CefSharp` and I was successful with that. We cannot however add Nuget packages to our project. They need to be referenced directly. Trying to implement CefSharp was not working. WebView2 is the alternative, and although it works navigating etc, trying to open the required ReportView URL that needs this cookie for validation is a show stopper.

When I add the 2 cookies (1 is the Session cookie for ASPNET, the second is our auth cookie) only the session cookie seems to be allocated.

This is the partial code:

I retrieve the cookies for IIS

```
   var sCookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri($"{m_sSessionURL}"), false);
```

This retrieves both the cookies. I add the cookies to WebView2 using
foreach (var item in sCookies)
{
var cookie = browser.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookieWithSystemNetCookie(item);
browser.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(cookie);
}

When I execute

```
     var cookies = await browser.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.GetCookiesAsync(m_sSessionURL);
```

to retieve the cookies again, it only retrieves the ASPNET Session cookie, and obviously the  ReportViewer does not open, but give me our custom error specifying that the session has expired.

I also tried

```
{
     ...
     browser.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);
     browser.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;
     ...
}
  private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
  {
     var m_sSessionURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionURL"];
     var sCookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri($"{m_sSessionURL}"), false);
     foreach (var item in sCookies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("somevalue")))
     {

        e.Request.Headers.SetHeader("Cookie", $"{item.Name}={item.Value}");
     }
  }
```

But this didn't do the trick either. What I noticed about WebView as well is that it keep asking me to select a certificate that the server needs, which did not happen with CefSharp. Do I miss something with the cookies that I need to do as well?